# Host Ping Service Start script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need some help with a Linux shell script which should automatically check if a host is reachable. It is best to ping port 22 every 3-5 seconds. If the port is reachable the program should execute the command service HelloWorld stop. If the host is not reachable, the script should automatically execute a command on the computer e.g. service HelloWorld start.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

I have something like this, but that not functionning,

```
#!/bin/bash
IP='192.168.1.1'
fping -c1 -t300 $IP 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
if [ "$?" = 0 ]
then
  service helloworld stop
else
  service helloworld start
fi
```

Comment: *"I have something like this, but that not function..."* - You should show your actual code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
IP='192.168.1.1'
PORT=22
(echo >/dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT) &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" = 0 ]
then
  service helloworld stop
else
  service helloworld start
fi
```

In this way, it's allowed to check IP with specific port is reachable or not